# Is there any way to prevent the default action of the Escape key in Electron?

Tags: javascript, events, electron

Is it possible to prevent the default action of the Escape key in an Electron app -- specifically, to prevent it from cancelling an in-progress drag and drop action in the Chrome window?  See this fiddle for example -- if you drag and hold the div and then press the Esc key, the drag is cancelled, even though there is an event listener that calls `e.preventDefault` on the event: https://jsfiddle.net/82aL6gsy/

Does Electron (or Chrome) provide any lower-level or less restricted APIs that we can use to intercept this?

Update: please note that this question is about whether or not the mentioned functionality can be achieved, not about why or whether doing so would be a good idea.

Comment: Why would you want to stop that behavior? What's the problem with stopping a drag&drop action?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I think the esc-cancels-drag-n-drop functionality may be implemented either as a special case within Chromium (although I couldn't find where), or as part of the desktop environment, in which case Chromium may not even see the event.  In any case, there is no associated `keydown` event for the key press that cancels the drag, and I don't think there is any way to intercept this behaviour from JavaScript, even in Electron.